# How to calculate maximum stress that can be taken by an object simply

Tags: experimental-physics, stress-strain

My goal is to calculate the amount of stress it takes for an object to fracture. I would like to conduct a three point bend test, without having to buy a machine for it. The object is a pig's fibula bone, and this is for research. Could you help me think of a method or an idea?

Comment: Gym weights, rope, and a steady base with measured marks.

Comment: big bucket that you slowly fill with sand..

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Comment: A slight alteration of Peter's idea:  Use a bucket with distilled water and a larger version of a titration apparatus so you can accurately measure the volume of water (thus the mass) added to the bucket.

Comment: Obviously you want to maximize the L to reduce the amount of force needed. Make the two points that hold the bone as far apart as you can but still holding it stable

Answer (score -1):

The suggestion by PeterR seems good to me : simple and cheap.

Position the bone so that it is stably supported between sturdy supports a distance $L$ apart. Suspend the bucket from a strong cord at the midpoint and gradually add stones until the bone breaks. You will need to repeat the measurement a few times to get an idea for how reliable and accurate it is.

The breaking stress is $$\sigma_b = \frac{PL}{\pi r^3}$$ where $P$ is the load at the breaking point, and $r$ is the average radius of the bone at the midpoint.

Comment: Sand can usually be dosed better than stones ;D otherwise I totally agree

Comment: True, but sand is more messy and may be more difficult to get hold of, and the additional accuracy is unlikely to be worth the effort.

Comment: I am a little disturbed by $3.12$. Is it supposed to be an approximation of $\pi = 3.1416...$? If so, then it fails at that. Or maybe there is a parenthesis missing $3.1 ( 2 r^3)$. Please clarify.

Comment: I’ve removed your link, which seems to have gone bad in the last five years: clicking it sends me through a bunch of spammy-looking redirects. Perhaps you can locate a better one.

Comment: Obviously you want to maximize the L to reduce the amount of force needed. Make the two points that hold the bone as far apart as you can but still holding it stable

Comment: @JohnAlexiou yes it is $\pi$